# Can I create a nested activity diagram in UML?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

For eg: I have an activity diagram depicting the flow of an API. Now that API calls an internal/static function. So, is it possible to depict the called function activity diagram with the caller activity diagram?

Comment: See https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html

Comment: looks like i can find useful info. from above link. thanks.

Comment: Just realize that you tagged it with EA. Are you seeking for technical options to do that with EA?

Comment: good observation. yes I am seeking options to achieve it in EA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve nesting in EA. One would be to create an `Activity` for the sub-process and invoke that.

You can nest the actions in an activity and use that in the main flow as invocation (when dragging the `Activity` on the diagram use as "Invocation"  rather than as "Link"). It then looks like

[image]

From the browser (well, it's EA) you can choose `Add/Composite Structure Diagram`. Here you can layout the subprocess (e.g. like)

[image]

When you double click the invocation it will open this structure diagram.

Additionally you can use this diagram and drag it onto the (enlarged) invocation so it would show its guts:

[image]

The way it's shown in [uml-diagrams.org](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html) is not possible for the diagram representation in EA (or I don't know how to do that). However, you can add `ObjectNode`s to `Activities` from the browser's `Add` context menu. These can be use in the referenced way.